# MiniProfiler with MongoDB Csharp Driver 2.01

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I would like to use the [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) with MongoDB but it looks like
there is only support for the MongoDB Driver Version 1.9.0. 
The current version of the MongoDB Csharp Driver is 2.0.1 and it has changed a lot.

Is there any workaround or fork on github available?

Comment: There is no workaround and it is not yet supported. If anyone wants to [submit a pull request](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/110) for this, we would be happy to work with that.

Comment: What the 2.x driver has added, though is event subscriptions. So subscribing to `CommandStartedEvent` & `CommandSucceededEvent` events would give a great input for the profiler.